# HTACCESS Custom redirect based on server URL and TLD

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-routing

I got the following setup

My website is located on at this server jdbartist.bplaced.net/gkn

I bought a TLD (gamekeynexus.com) and set it up to redirect to the gkn directory, so when I type my tld into the browser window I get to my site on my server and it says gamekeynexus.com in the browser = awesome!  Now the only thing that bothers me is that

**IF** someone **KNOWS** the old address, he's able to reach the site via this old address (i.e type jdbartist.bplaced.net/gkn)

*My question would be, how can I redirect calls to my old URL to my new URL?*

I guess an htaccess redirect would do the job, but I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this snippet of PHP could be helpful

```
<? 
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'jdbartist.bplaced.net') { 
header("Location: http://gamekeynexus.com/");
}
?>
```

Comment: Awesome! I am so sorry I didn't find that myself! Forgive me, just started learning PHP a week ago

Comment: I suggested the PHP code simply because i did not know what methods you had used to redirect your TLD. @Sven code was indeed the correct way via .htaccess however not knowing your internal web structure makes it difficult to offer the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple rewriting:

```
RewriteCond !%{HTTP_HOST}  newdomain
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain/$1 [L]
```

Have a look at the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: So I came up with this but it throws me an 'never ending loop' error  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond !%{HTTP_HOST}  gamekeynexus.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://gamekeynexus.com/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`